# Initiating Bootstrap plugins

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap, mysqli

This may seem like a basic kind of question, I have just downloaded the Bootstrap files for my new website, I have attempted to include a dropdown button from the bootstrap examples, as below...

```
<div class="btn-group">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Action</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
    <span class="caret"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

The button shows fine but is not dropping down, other little bits of the bootstrap examples work fine such as the animated progress bar. I am not sure if I need to add more script codes in the head section to activate the files?

The header currently looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>FundFeeder | Welcome</title>
<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all">
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="keywords" content="Wowphotos Responsive web template, Bootstrap Web Templates, Flat Web Templates, Andriod Compatible web template, 
Smartphone Compatible web template, free webdesigns for Nokia, Samsung, LG, SonyErricsson, Motorola web design" />
<script type="application/x-javascript"> addEventListener("load", function() { setTimeout(hideURLbar, 0); }, false); function hideURLbar(){ window.scrollTo(0,1); } </script>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu:300,400,500,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.easydropdown.js"></script>
<script>$(document).ready(function(c) {
    $('.alert-close').on('click', function(c){
        $('.message').fadeOut('slow', function(c){
            $('.message').remove();
        });
    });   
});
</script>
<script>$(document).ready(function(c) {
    $('.alert-close1').on('click', function(c){
        $('.message1').fadeOut('slow', function(c){
            $('.message1').remove();
        });
    });   
});
</script>

</head>
```

But I have a lot more files?

```
- bootstrap
- bootstrap.css
- bootstrap.min
- bootstrap-theme
```

etc...

Comment: I think you might be missing the bootstrap js file

Comment: I haven't included all files in the question, in my JS folder I have bootstrap, bootstrap.min, jquery.min and npm ??

Comment: do you have `bootstrap.min.js` ?

Comment: Yeah I have that one in my JS folder.

Comment: All of these were add-ons to the template so I'm not sure if they automatically include or if I have to add them manually?

Comment: then you should include it in your HTML `<script src="pathToFile/bootstrap.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Just added that code in the head section but still no change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap's plugins are jquery dependant. So you need to load that first.

Then either load all bootstraps plugins with 'bootstrap.js' or load a particular plugin by downloading it from the bootstrap customiser.

Loading is not enough though. You then need to 'call' the function you want to use on the page.

In your case, using all, add as follows:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script>$('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown()</script>
```

FYI - your new template seems a bit messy. Are you using all that js? If not, delete the js and copy the above and put it at the bottom of your page - just above the `</body>` - so doesn't slow down page load.

Comment: Worked perfectly, thanks so much & I will look at cleaning it up a bit, thanks for the advice :)

Answer (score 0):

If you need an additional method, the below lines should make your dropdown function correctly.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```